# how can I make an fbox like command with certain color, shape and width of border?

Tags: color, boxes, framed

I am using a style file that has a certain color for section headers.

I want to create a macro, which will behave the same like fbox, only:

1. There will be some (predefined) padding below, above, left and right of the border.
2. The border will have a certain (predefined) width, which is thicker than the default.
3. The color of the border will be the same color as the section headers (is there a variable that denotes section header text color?)
4. The shape of the border will be oval on the corners, and not pointy.

How would I go on in defining such a macro?

Comment: See package `tcolorbox`

Comment: apart from 4 the standard `\fcolorbox` does exactly that but for rounded corners you will need a pstricks or tikz based box macro (or at least, it's simpler that way)

Answer (score 2):

As show in the comments, an easy solution is the `tcolorbox` package using tikz in the background. Another is the `mdframed` package. Both give highly configurables environments of the same names. See `texdoc tcolorbox` and `texdoc mdframed` for the options.

An example to start with both:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
colframe=blue!25,
colback=blue!10,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,  
}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
backgroundcolor=blue!10,
frametitlebackgroundcolor=blue!25,
middlelinecolor=blue!25,
linewidth=1.5pt,
roundcorner=4pt,
innertopmargin=1ex,
innerbottommargin=.5\baselineskip,
innerrightmargin=1.5em,
innerleftmargin=1em
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=The title]
    This is a tcolorbox
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame,frametitle=The title]
    This is a mdframed box
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```